# Can't move certain files in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, google-classroom

I'm a student, and currently trying to organize all of my documents and slideshows into folders for easy access.
Although, some of these documents and slides I cant move, the option is just greyed out.

It might be worth noting that these documents and slides have been submitted into classroom, but I don't think this is the sole reason, as I can still move other documents that I have submitted to various folders.
Is there a way to still move these documents? All it does is create a shortcut, which isn't what I want as I'm trying to clean everything up.

Here is an image down below:
[image: this is whats appearing]

Answer (score 0):

You mention

> trying to organize all of my documents and slideshows into
> folders...some of these documents and slides I cant move, the option
> is just greyed out.
>
> ...these documents and slides have been submitted into classroom...

You cannot move your documents any more because **you do not have editing rights any more**. You just have viewing rights.
You will also notice that you can neither delete these files.

That is default behaviour in classroom which is controlled by your teacher/professor so that -for example- submitted work cannot be altered by students (especially when there is a deadline).

To answer your question, *"Is there a way to still move these documents?"*, no you cannot.

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's import to highlight that the files were submitted as classwork in Google Classroom.

When you **as student** add files from Google Drive to Classroom assigments, once you submit the assigment the files ownership is trasferred to the teacher. You will not able to do some actions on these files like move them because you are no longer the file owner.

You will be able to move the files

- by unsubmitting the assigment
  Be cautions about doing this as your assignment will be marked as unsubmitted and if you submit again after the due date it will be marked late.
- when the teacher return the assigment to you. This could be done, i.e., to ask you to edit the files to do some corrections, or once the assigment is graded.

References

- [Turn in an assignment](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6020285?hl=en)
- [How attachments are shared in Classroom](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6020260?hl=en)
- [Answer by Richard Napolitano Platinum Product Expert](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/thread/129727877?hl=en&msgid=129730296) to [Moving Drive Files Submitted on Classroom](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/thread/129727877?hl=en)